# How to highlight my calendar when a new date is entered in an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, calendar, jscalendar

So I have two calendars on my page, when I select dates it then shows those selected dates in the  fields I have created. But what I want to do is that; if the user changes those dates (or any of them) manually, I want my calendar to then update the dates too and keep them highlighted.

```
<div class="check-in">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="check_in" name="Checkin" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY"required>
        </div>

        <div class="check-out">
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="check_out" name="Checkout" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" required>
        </div>
enter code here

function selectDates(selected) {
            if (!$.isEmptyObject(selected)) {
                var dateElements1 = datesBody1.find('div');
                var dateElements2 = datesBody2.find('div');

                function highlightDates(passed_year, passed_month, dateElements){
                    if (passed_year in selected && passed_month in selected[passed_year]) {
                        var daysToCompare = selected[passed_year][passed_month];
                        // console.log(daysToCompare);
                        for (var d in daysToCompare) {
                            dateElements.each(function(index) {
                                if (parseInt($(this).text()) == daysToCompare[d]) {
                                    $(this).addClass('selected');
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }
                }

                highlightDates(year, month, dateElements1);
                highlightDates(nextYear, nextMonth, dateElements2);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, and your example is not reproducible with the code you've given, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example What exactly are you trying to do? If you're trying to do what I think you're trying to do, I would say the easiest way to implement this would be through the vue.js framework. See "Handling User Input" section at this url: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for getting back to me. Basically, I have two input fields which handles the check-in and check-out dates. I have a calendar on my page where users can select dates. Once dates are selected it then appears in the input fields. What I want to do is to reverse engineer that, so if a user changes the dates manually it then move the highlighted dates on the calendar too.

Comment: Okay, definitely I think vue would be the way to solve this problem. Vue is very simple to use and provides data binding. So you could reverse the process very simply